# BsonSerializationException: Creator map for class has 2 arguments, but none are configured

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a `TextSearchJob` object to store on MongoDB.

I am rather new with the database and I don't know why I have this error with the `IDictionary` version (on the right) while I have no error with the `IEnumerable` version(on the left):
`MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: Creator map for class TextSearchJob has 2 arguments, but none are configured.`

Can someone explain this or point me to a documentation?
[image: Comparison of working and buggy versions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that **if the constructor parameter name matches the property name**, it must be of the same type.
For my constructor, I wanted to have a type different from the property. So to solve my problem, I had to give a parameter name different from the property's to be able to use a different type... Go figure. :/

So, I just renamed my parameter `inputs` to `kvInputs`, and it worked.

Comment: I don't think that it's a good solution, you can break serialization assumptions and didn't notice like something in your output will be broken. I think there are expected ways to workaround it. I would try playing with `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap` first.

Comment: Thanks for the `RegisterClassMap` tip. I saw that, but I understand that it is used to customize serialization. I just want to use a constructor overload for my needs and let the serialization to be performed from BSON conventions. It seems that constructors are important for BSON serialization. Do you know why ?

Comment: `it is used to customize serialization` yes, it's used to configure serialization in particular what parts of your class participate in serialization (and deserialization).  `Do you know why ?` - if I recall correctly, ctor is called to create an instance for immutable classes. So values that presents in bson document (that match by name and type) will be passed as arguments into ctor and then class will be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

FieldName and his type should match to argument in ctor with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me find a way to workaround the exception.